# Using a batch file to write passwords from a browser to a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, cmd, passwords

I am looking to collect passwords from a web browser using a batch file and some other tools and writing them to a .txt file. Any suggestions for tools/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but you could make a batch or python script to move all the files found in these folders onto a thumbdrive:

```
C:\Program Files\BROWSER
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\BROWSER
```

after they're on your thumbdrive you'd be able to move them onto your computer (into the corresponding locations) and open the browser up and log onto their 'remembered accounts'. I know for a fact that firefox stores all your passwords in the 'logins.json' or 'signons.sqlite' and 'key3.db' files in the appdata folder, but as for other browsers like IE or chrome I have no idea.

As for an already existing solution, here is a link that will supposedly steal passwords, but usually websites with the word 'hacker' in the URL shouldn't be trusted.

http://www.hackershandbook.org/tutorials/usb-password-stealer

Be careful and don't do anything that would get you in trouble.

-Robbie